# How to use PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper in luke tool?

Tags: lucene, luke

How to use **PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper** in **Luke** tool ? For one field we have **KeywordAnalyzer** and other field **StandardAnalyzer**, So want to search using PerfieldAnalyzer in Luke tool, using **Lucene** 4.2.0. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is no way of using different analyzers for a field in Luke. I would recommend to write simple Java program, which will open existing index and then use **PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper** for search, so you could specify needed analyzers for desired fields.